# Equivalents to ' glColor3ubv(&color[i * 3])' and 'glVertex3f(x, y,(float) depth_float)' in OpenGL-ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, point-clouds

I am porting an existing OpenGL application to Android. I have issues with finding equivalents to these functions in OpenGL-ES:

```
1)    glColor3ubv(&color[i * 3]);
2)    glVertex3f(x, y,(float) depth_float);
```

From ' Khoronos's ' documentation and other blogs I rewrote the functions this way which however is not doing things as expected:

```
1)    glColor4ub(color[i*3], color[i*3 + 1], color[i*3 + 2], color[i*3]);
2)    glVertexPointer(x, y,(float) depth_float,0);
```

Can you look into this?

Comment: I'll repeat what I said in your [cross-posted question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73909/equivalents-to-glcolor3ubvcolori-3-and-glvertex3fx-y-float-depth). You should consider [reading the documentation of the functions you are calling](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml).

Comment: `glColor`, `glVertex`, and other 'immediate mode rendering' functions are not available in OpenGL 3+ or OpenGL ES. You need to upload your vertex attributes to a buffer object, and render them from there.

Comment: `glVertexPointer (...)` is ***very*** different from `glVertex3f (...)` and assuming you are not using the NDK, then you have to consider the fact that Java doesn't have unsigned data types before using something like `glColor4ub (...)`. There is a trick you have to do, that involves promoting your byte to a larger integer data type and masking off the sign-bit to make that work in Java.